# Single Page Application with 2 Data sources | Vue.Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lazy-loading, single-page-application

I'm working on a Single Page Application with vue.js

I have 2 bundles of pages saved in separate S3 buckets.

1 bundle is public, and 1 is private.
Meaning, public bundle is supposed to be visible to all the users and private should be visible to only some specific authorised users.
And authorised users should be able to see the public pages as well.

Problem here is, since I have 2 different bundles, how can I still keep it as a single page application, and keep the navigation from private to public pages smooth?

I'm very new to frontend and vue.js

As per my knowledge *I might need to use dynamic loading here, but is there any better way *?

Answer (score 0):

you can set a condition in your router and specify access to your pages

```
const routes = [
     {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home,
      meta: {
        hasAccess: false, //page you want to be public
      }
    },
     {
      path: '/adminPanel',
      name: 'AdminPanel',
      component: AdminPanel,
      meta: {
        hasAccess: true, //page you want to be private
      }
    }
]

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
    routes,
})

    router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
      const hasAccess = Boolean(localStorage.getItem('isLocalAdmin')); //your condition
      if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.hasAccess) && !hasAccess) {
        next('/'); //any page you want to send user with no access
      }
    });

export default router
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the actually issue is not restricting user access.

The issue is, since I have 2 separate bundles saved in 2 different locations (because of security concern)
When ever user jumps from public to private page, I'll have to load data again, and would break the purpose of Single Page Application, because it would take some time to load.